# How to prevent lodash map from creating a nested object?

Tags: lodash

I want to map an array of objects and add a property to each item. At the moment the original values get nested. How can I change it to get an item with a flattened object?

[code example](https://repl.it/repls/FewHarshForce)

```
import _ from 'lodash';

let arr = [{name: "tim"}, {name: "tom"}]
const id = {id: 1}

console.dir(_.map(arr, item => ({...id, item})));
```

result:

```
[ { id: 1, item: { name: 'tim' } },
  { id: 1, item: { name: 'tom' } } ]
```

wished result:

```
[ { id: 1,  name: 'tim'  },
  { id: 1,  name: 'tom' } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread the `item` as well:

```js
let arr = [{name: "tim"}, {name: "tom"}]
const id = {id: 1}

console.dir(_.map(arr, item => ({ ...id, ...item })));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Or use `_.merge()` with lodash/fp:

```js
const mergeId = id => _.map(_.merge(id))

let arr = [{name: "tim"}, {name: "tom"}]
const id = {id: 1}

result = mergeId(id)(arr)

console.dir(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```